# Replace Part of a String Leaving Part In Place based on a match

Tags: regex

I have a large set of files that were misnamed for the application they are used in.  Unfortunately not all the files have the issue, so I need to find those matching my pattern and then replace part of the string.

Error Format: Dayton_Springfield-Troy.xml

Correct Format: Dayton-Springfield_Troy.xml

I could find all the errors with: `.*_.*-`
But I am too much of a novice to do an effective replace regex to get the correct format back without deleting my market name and city name.

Comment: To the person who voted to close this as "too broad", you might want to give some slack here. The question is completely clear except for knowing exactly which tool is being used.

Comment: Do you have only 1 underscore and 1 dash in a filename? Is the filename alone in a string/line or are there other characters before and/or after the filename?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what tools you are using so I can only give a generic answer.

The regex search you need is something like (untested):

```
^(.*)_(.*)-(.*)\.xml$
```

And the replace (note that the token id's will depend on the tool used):

```
$1-$2_$3.xml
```

Comment: @op, this is a regular expression technique called "Capture Groups". The parentheses break the string up into 3 groups 1, 2, and 3. the replace string uses references to these groups to define how they will be used in the rewritten string. most tools use $ to delimit groups, but sometimes its % or other characters. you will need to use a renaming tool that supports regex, and define the search and replace strings as Julian Knight has indicated.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I am using a tool called Bulk Rename Utility and SR64.exe.  Let me see if I can grok your advice and get it to work.  Thank you very much for jumping in.

Comment: I have the guide for the tool.  I should be able to find if $, % or something else is the delimiter.

Comment: @Givings For Bulk Rename Utility, to adapt the answer above, you will likely want to use `^(.*)_(.*)-(.*)` (since the extension should be already accounted for by BRU) and replace "$" with "\" for the replacement groups (so `\1-\2_\3` versus `$1-$2_$3`).

Comment: Thanks guys for chipping in and making the answer better.